# Ado net command time out in property in sqlcommand?

Tags: ado.net

In webapplication, I put

```
sqlcommand.CommandTimeout=0;
```

Is this statement is recommended or not [good progamming style], or which one is good if it is not good?

Comment: If you're ready to wait **forever** ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` documentation:

> A value of 0 indications no limit, and should be avoided

It could cause the request and the thread processes it to hang indefinitely. This is a waste of resources if nothing else.

It would also make it harder to identify if you have commands that are not completing in a reasonable time.

> is this statement is recommended or no

Not.

Comment: +1 Overriding the command timeout is somewhat of the last resort - if the problem can already be tracked down to a single command it should be possible to find a better solution.